# assign a value to a println statement so it can be used anywhere in the file

Tags: java, variables, declare, println

I need to assign a value to a println statement so that i can declare it as a variable and then use it anywhere in the code. i want to be able to assign a value to the "result" in the println, however i do not know how to do this. Does anyone know how to assign a value to this so that it can be used anywhere?
I have tried the following, however i get an error saying that void cannot be converted to string...

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method:

```
private void print(String value) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

This can be called from anywhere in your class.

If you would like to re-use this functionality in different classes you could create a separate class for it:

```
public class Printer {
    public void print(String value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

You can then add it as a dependency in the class that wants to print:

```
public class MyApp {

    private Printer printer;

    public MyApp(Printer printer) {
        this.printer = printer;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        printer.print("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a Consumer and pass a object whenever you want to print taht object.

```
Consumer consumer= System.out::println;
consumer.accept(5);
```

**Updated**

In your case define consumer as :

```
public static int myHouseValue;
public static final Consumer CONSUMER= System.out::println;
```

and any where and in any class you can use this consumer. just include this static member. and pass the object you want to print.

```
CONSUMER.accept(5);
CONSUMER.accept("String");
CONSUMER.accept(new Object());
CONSUMER.accept(myHouseValue);
```

**Your Code (Updated):**

```
public class Weka {

  public static int Lotsize;
  public static int Bedrooms;
  public static int LocalSchools;
  public static int Age;
  public static int Garages;
  public static int Bathrooms;


  public static double myHouseValue = 0d;// here is the default value zero
  public static final Consumer CONSUMER = System.out::println;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Server up and running");



      . . .


      your code


      . . . 



    // donot declare myHouseValue again , its already defined wher we set it to default value. only use here
    myHouseValue = (coef[0] * Lotsize) +
        (coef[1] * Bedrooms) +
        (coef[2] * LocalSchools) +
        (coef[3] * Age) +
        (coef[4] * Garages) +
        (coef[5] * Bathrooms) +
        coef[7];

    CONSUMER.accept(myHouseValue);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186473/discussion-on-answer-by-khalid-shah-assign-a-value-to-a-println-statement-so-it).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably write it as a JAVA lambda expression, such as:

```
Consumer<String> print = it-> System.out.println(it);
```

Whenever you want to run, you can run it like this:

```
print.accept("hello");
```

Br,

Tim